# Oracle: a query, which counts occurrences of all non alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, alphanumeric

What would be the best way to count occurrences of all non alphanumeric characters that appear in a string in an Oracle database column.

When attempting to find a solution I realised I had a query that was unrelated to the problem, but I noticed I could modify it in the hope to solve this problem. I came up with this:

```
SELECT  COUNT (*), SUBSTR(TITLE, REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(TITLE), '[^A-Z,^0-9]'), 1)
FROM    TABLE_NAME
WHERE   REGEXP_LIKE(UPPER(TITLE), '[^A-Z,^0-9]')
GROUP BY    SUBSTR(TITLE, REGEXP_INSTR(UPPER(TITLE), '[^A-Z,^0-9]'), 1)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This works to find the FIRST non alphanumeric character, but I would like to count the occurrences throughout the entire string, not just the first occurrence. E. g. currently my query analysing "a (string)" would find one open parenthesis, but I need it to find one open parenthesis and one closed parenthesis.

Comment: Unforunately I need to be able to find how many occurances of each symbol have been found, has anyone any ideas for this? I tried to get this across in the last paragraph of my question.

Comment: Do you need the count of non-alphanumeric characters or the count of **each** non-alphanumeric character?  For instance, for the string "(1(2)3)", do you want the result to be 4 or to somehow indicate 2 "(" and 2 ")"?

Comment: @Allan yes 2 ( and 2 ), however I decided to write a quick pl-sql procedure to do this for me, as speed wasn't a big issue (I was only going to run this once for design purposes), so this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option, as you discovered is to use a PL/SQL procedure.  I don't think there's any way to create a regex expression that will return multiple counts like you're expecting (at least, not in Oracle).

One way to get around this is to use a recursive query to examine each character individually, which could be used to return a row for each character found.  The following example will work for a single row:

```
with d as (
   select '(1(2)3)' as str_value
   from dual)
select char_value, count(*)
from (select substr(str_value,level,1) as char_value
      from d
      connect by level <= length(str_value))
where regexp_instr(upper(char_value), '[^A-Z,^0-9]'), 1) <> 0
group by char_value;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an obscure Oracle TRANSLATE function that will let you do that instead of regexp:

```
select a.*,
       length(translate(lower(title),'.0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','.')) 
from table_name a
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT  a.*, LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(TITLE, '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'), '')
FROM    TABLE_NAME a
```